# Details of a list item in a list view

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listitem

I am trying to pass some details of a list item to a new activity. 
Unfortunately I get always the details of the first item of the list on the new activity. This is due to the name of the textview (I suppose) that are named with the same name. How can I get the ones related to the item clicked?

```
public class GetFloor extends ListActivity {

  private Context context;
  private static String url = "http://indoorlocation.altervista.org/JSON/floor.php";

  private static final String FLOORID = "FloorID";
  private static final String BUILDINGID = "BuildingID";
  private static final String FLOORNAME = "FloorName";
  private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 ListView lv ;

 TextView txFloorid;
 TextView txBuildingid;
 TextView txFloorname;
 TextView txDescription;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getfloor);
    new ProgressTask(GetFloor.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ListActivity activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist, R.layout.floorlist, new String[] { FLOORID, BUILDINGID, FLOORNAME, DESCRIPTION}, new int[] { R.id.FloorID, R.id.BuildingID, R.id.FloorName, R.id.Description});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // select single ListView item
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                txFloorid = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.FloorID);
                txBuildingid = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.BuildingID);

                txFloorname = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.FloorName);
                txDescription = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.Description);

                Intent intent = new Intent(GetFloor.this, FloorDetails.class);

                intent.putExtra("floorid", txFloorid.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("buildingid", txBuildingid.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("floorname", txFloorname.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("description", txDescription.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // get JSON data from URL
    JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            try {
            JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
            String floorid = c.getString(FLOORID);
                String buildingid = c.getString(BUILDINGID);
            String floorname = c.getString(FLOORNAME);
            String description = c.getString(DESCRIPTION);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // Add child node to HashMap key & value
            map.put(FLOORID, floorid);
                map.put(BUILDINGID, buildingid);
            map.put(FLOORNAME, floorname);
            map.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
                jsonlist.add(map);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
}
}
```

Here below the class that I created to get the extra data passed from the first activity.

```
 public class FloorDetails extends Activity {


private static final String FLOORID = "FloorID";
private static final String BUILDINGID = "BuildingID";
private static final String FLOORNAME = "FloorName";
private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

TextView floorid;
TextView buildingid;
TextView floorname;
TextView description;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.floordetails);


    floorid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FloorID);
    buildingid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BuildingID);

    floorname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FloorName);
   description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description);


    // get the intent from which this activity is called.
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // fetch value from key-value pair and make it visible on TextView.

    String FloorID = intent.getStringExtra("floorid");
    String BuildingID = intent.getStringExtra("buildingid");
    String FloorName = intent.getStringExtra("floorname");
    String Description = intent.getStringExtra("description");


    floorid.setText(FLOORID + ":" + FloorID);
    buildingid.setText(BUILDINGID +  ":"  + BuildingID);
     floorname.setText(FLOORNAME + ":" + FloorName);
    description.setText(DESCRIPTION + ":" + Description) ;

}
}
```

Here below the xml file related to the floorlist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/FloorID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FloorID" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/BuildingID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BuildingID" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/FloorName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FloorName" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I apologize for the bad format of my code.

Thank you in advance,
Celair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `onItemClick()` method, you should do `view.findViewById(...)` instead of `parent.findViewById(...)`